# Database that supports sublinear query over ranges

Tags: database

Is there a database technology that supports efficient queries / indexing within a continuous range of values?  For example consider the following data set

```
Name      Age
Alice     25
Bob       35
Charlie   26
Diane     39
Edward    19
...       ...
```

Now imagine I want to do a query for the names of all people in their twenties.  I can express this query in a number of database systems.  Is there any system which supports efficient/sublinear queries of this sort?  By sublinear I mean that it does not need to look at every entry in the table/database but can quickly select the relevant rows by looking at some other data structure.  I'm looking for something like an index but over ordered and continuous data.  The particular ordered/continuous column over which I want to filter is of type Datetime.

Note that I'm not looking for a query to solve this problem.  I'm looking for an example database system that supports efficient (sublinear) filtering over ordered continuous data.

If no such system exists I'd also be happy to learn of research/papers in this area.

Comment: This is _way_ too broad; you first have to define efficient. With the correct indexing and especially partitioning most relational databases will be fast over millions of rows at this sort of query. You're obviously not thinking of a standard relational database so maybe you could explain what you class as "efficient".

Comment: I've changed efficient in the title to sublinear

Comment: Okay, so you don't want a relational database but the assumption is that wherever the data is stored it's ordered so that you only need to find the largest and smallest records within your range so that you can get everything in between without having to ask the disks whether it is in fact between these records? i.e. you want extremely slow writes and extremely quick reads?

Comment: I didn't specify a need for a relational database but I don't think the two ideas are exclusive.  This is an implementation question, not a data-model question.  Sublinear was in the body of the question prior to your original comment.  I've added it again and a more in depth explanation to the body.  I don't want extremely slow writes but I'm aware that the naive solution to solve this problem would sacrifice write time.

Comment: I don't think they are either; which is why I mentioned partitioning in my first comment; given a finite set of queries like the one's mentioned above you can pull out everything in a single partition because that's everything that fits your query's parameters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure nearly all DBMS will be able to use an index for the condition `age between 20 and 29` - I'd say that qualifies as "sublinear".

Comment: As long as you do not need to filter on *two* ranges, any old RDBMS can do this. Research how B-trees work and you see why range scans are easily implemented.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "efficient" and "sublinear" as in "not a full-table scan" then any of the major relational databases can do this if you place an index onto your column.

Both integer columns as well as timestamp columns are perfectly usable for this, because their ordering is quite simple and the width of the column is fixed and small - hence the index is very efficient.

Since the index is usually a btree index (or a variant thereof) the index is ordered by default. And a range query just means: Pick the appropriate subtree and be done. Traversing a tree with this criteria is sublinear.

Example: Using PostgreSQL:

```
> select count(*) from objects;
34215157
Time: 4423,262 ms

> explain select * from objects where objects_pkey between 42 and 42000;
                                 QUERY PLAN                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using objects_pkey on objects  (cost=0.00..1920.84 rows=40292 width=288)
   Index Cond: ((objects_pkey >= 42) AND (objects_pkey <= 42000))

> select count(*) from objects where objects_pkey between 42 and 42000;
 count 
-------
 41959
Time: 15,403 ms
```

Which means: The table is quite big and does not fit into memory. The index scan using an integer column is bound by two criteria (meaning: efficient access). Fetching ~40k rows only takes 15ms.

BTW: This kind of access you are asking for is a) nothing new or exciting and b) exactly the kind of query relational databases are born for and tuned for about three decades.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @A.H.!  This is news to me.  Are you able to supply a reference?

Comment: @MRocklin: for what part do you want "reference"?

Comment: @MRocklin: see the execution plan: that *is* your reference. You can always reproduce (test) that for yourself.

Comment: I guess I'd like a document that explains PostgreSQL's indexing system on integer valued columns.  Your example clearly demonstrates the truth of your answer.  I'd like somewhere where I can read more.  If you don't have something handy I can always go googling.

Comment: @MRocklin You can start DB-agnostic by reading the Wikipedia articles about "b-tree" and "search tree" . Since this is DB 101 it applies to all DBs.

Comment: @MRocklin: it seems that you did not work much with modern relational databases. *Any* modern DBMS works that way.

Comment: It is important to note that although index based access is great for small proportions of a table's rows, it is inefficient in comparison to a full table scan as the proportion of rows read increases (if the table has to be accessed). When you get over something in the order of 5-15% of the total rows, you might almost as well use a full table scan. Now that may vary with SSD's or Flash storage, but it's an important limitation to consider.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's right, databases are not my field.  I've always felt comfortable asking novice questions on stackoverflow.  Please let me know if I cross some line of ignorance and should go elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If this were something like a very large data warehouse fact table with a time component on it by which the data had to be efficiently queried (say, DATE_OF_SALE), then a common implementation would be a relational database table that is partitioned on that value.

In Oracle this would typically be range partitioning, so I'll address how that is implemented internally.

A regular unpartitioned table can be considered to be a set of column and table metadata (table name, column names and data types etc) and a "physical" data segment that stores the actual data. A full table scan requires that this data segment be read for every block under the High Water Mark.

Partitioning breaks the table into multiple segments, each of which is logically constrained to hold a particular set of data. That could be a set defined by a list of values for a particular column (the partitioning key), of the result of a hash function applied to a column, or in this case a range of values of a column.

The query optimiser detects the presence of a predicate on a partition key column, and attempts to isolate the minimum set of partitions which might contain candidate data. These can then be scanned, or accessed via indexes dedicated to each partition. This is known as Partition Pruning, and results in much faster scans of the data due to the elimination of large data sets from consideration.

In more engineered systems, such as Oracle's Exadata, there can be structures that store the maximum and minimum values of columns for sets of contiguous data blocks, sized in the low megabytes range. In this case a full scan of a table or partition can eliminate scans of these sets of data blocks by eliminating the possibility that candidate rows exist in them. Oracle calls these structures Storage Indexes.

So, apologies for the Oracle-heavy approach, but similar implementations exist in other relational and non-relational databases, and they can offer much greater performance than indexes.

One issue with indexes, by the way, is that there is no implicit organisation of the table's data, so an index scan of 20% of the table data is quite possibly going to be less efficient than a full scan of the data due to repeated single block access of the table's data segment. Some RDBMS's allow the physical order of the rows to be set -- PostgreSQL allows clustering of the table by an index's columns, which makes a one-off rewrite of the table in the order of the index, which improves index-based access until the data becomes disorganised due to the addition of new rows or update of existing rows.

Comment: Doesn't Oracle support clustering or covering indexes as well?

Comment: Covering indexes are known in Oracle as Index Organised Tables, but to be applicable in this case the data would have to be part of the Primary Key. Clustering is also supported, but it's not widely used for this sort of query optimisation as far as I know -- it's more used for supporting high performance joins in an OLTP system. Hash clustering is good for colocation of rows with equal values, but that doesn't help with range-based queries as ranges are not stored contiguously.

Comment: A covering index in Oracle terms is an "index scan". A regular (B-Tree) index can be a "covering index" just as well. IOTs are what other DBMS refer to as "clustered index".

Answer (score -1):

MySQL is a database system where you can execute efficient queries. e.g. To get all people in their twenties, you can use the following query:
    SELECT Name FROM my_table WHERE Age BETWEEN 20 AND 29;

Comment: Note that I'm not looking for a query to solve this problem. I'm looking for an example database system that supports efficient (sublinear) filtering over ordered continuous data.

Comment: MySQL is a database system that supports efficient filter, too. To order SELECT results, write ORDER BY some_field

Comment: Is it sublinear or does it have to look at each entry in the table?

Comment: It will get every entry in the table that fulfills the given condition (e.g., Age between 20 and 29) and will show it ordered if specified

Comment: But will it have to look at each entry in the table to get the correct entries.  This is usually this case.  I'm looking for something, like an index, which allows the database implementation to quickly find a relevant subset in less time than it would take to scan through the entire dataset.

Comment: MySQL allows you to add a field that acts like an index. See this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: @PedroSpecian: "*a field that acts like an index*" is nonsense. A column is something completely different than an index in a relational database.

Comment: When I said "a field that acts like an index", I meant a primary key. It can be used like an index